# How can we handle Javascript enabled drop down using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

The drop-down is enabled after clicking on the text-box using JavaScript and I am unable to locate the element from the drop-down and select it. 
I have tried using JavaScript executor which is clicking on the element in the drop-down but the text box doesn't display it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the html code that relates to dropdown you mentioned above. It will be easier for other people can take a look and give their ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when select an element from the dropdown, the textbox should get enable based on the selection. Below is the code that works for me.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown button xpath-expression")).click();
    WebElement othersOp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown element xpath expression"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(othersOp).click().build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Boolean textBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Textbox id")).isDisplayed();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Textboxid']")).sendKeys("Testing");
    System.out.println("Textbox is displayed? "+textBox);
```